# read() on client side failing C

Tags: c, sockets, client

I have problems with a read() statement where I'm passing an integer from a server to the client. The problem is that I can send 2 integers to the server just fine, but for some reason the client fails to receive anything from the server except 0. Could someone explain to me what is actually going on with this while loop? It seems like a standard practice in C Sockets, but I can't figure out what (if anything) it is really accomplishing.

```
memset(rbuffer,0,sizeof(rbuffer));
while ( (n = read(sockfd, rbuffer, sizeof(rbuffer))) > 0)
{
    rbuffer[n] = 0;
}
```

This is the read attempt on the client side, where rbuffer is supposed to accept a single integer. It appears that it attempts to read over and over from the server (recieving n > 0 until the server closes the socket) where the last read before the socket closes actually holds the data, thus, rbuffer is set to 0 until completion, where it is then filled with the data from the server.

The code on the server side to send to the client appears like this:

```
int g = dijkstra(source, destination, numNodes);
printf("The value sent to client is %d.\n", g);
write(connfd, g, sizeof(g));

close(connfd);
  sleep(1);
```

and the original code appears as:

```
int g = dijkstra(source, destination, numNodes);
sprintf(sendBuff,"%d", g);
write(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff)); 

close(connfd);
  sleep(1);
```

But I want to read it as an integer at the client side and so I cut out sendBuff as it seemed unnecessary when sending an int, considering g was already set.

I appreciate any help. What I would like is a better understanding of the server to client communication of TCP sockets in C, specifically does read need to wait for a server response, or does it do that already? Also, cutting out the while loop for the read has no effect, the response is still 0 from the server for *buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `write(connfd, g, sizeof(g));`, the `write` function is expecting a char pointer as second parameter, and you are giving it a `int`. This is without saying that your original client is probably also expecting a string, filling out rbuffer with the characters, and adding the ending zero (`rbuffer[n] = 0`) to be able to use it as string for extracting the integer. You probably have a sscanf() on the client side.

What you are **literally** trying to do is this

```
write(connfd, (char*)&g, sizeof(g));
```

And could receive it as such, after the while, g being an `int`

```
g = *((int*)rbuffer);
```

But I should not even propose this, as it is not proper code...

Comment: I thought in C, that a char array was the same as an int array, but null terminated (to prevent going out of bounds). I've also read that write and read can process any data considering your sizeof is configured correctly (ex: an int[3] would be sizeof(int)*3).

Comment: Your first assumption is wrong, a char is not an int, and a char array is only null-terminated by convention, when used as a string. You are right on your second part, though, but your variable g is an int, not an array of int, nor a pointer to an int.

Comment: Thanks, I've read that scanf() can separate delimited strings and split them into integers, so I think I'll move back to using strings and use scan f to extract the numbers rather than try to force sending integers back and forth, when write isn't intended to do that. Thank you for clarifying read() and write().

Comment: There are ways to use a binary communication in a graceful manner, though. If you want to send and receive multiple values, you could create and send a struct, known by the client and the server. Don't get me wrong, I don't like the type casting from int to char*, but using an explicit convention for converting the byte array (char*) to your values is acceptable.